# Troubleshooting text spinning in divs that it should not be

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am currently building a grid layout web page with divs, I have 4 divs (the step divs) rotating using css animation however for some reasons the divs in the middle column are meant to be totally static, however the text is spinning in these too.

My source code is  [on my webpage](http://www.mildenhire.com/Website/graphiciframe.html)

***HTML OF A SPINNING TEXT DIV THAT SHOULD BE STATIC***

```
<div class="trigger">
    <div class="slider2">
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #CCCCB2; border-radius: 5px; height: 200px; width: 200px; color: #CCC;"  class="testimony">
            <div class="caption-box">Web Updates</div>
            <div class="just_text">
                <p style="margin: 10px 20px;">Our service also includes a money saving update scheme. For a monthly fee you can have updates to keep your site fresh and dynamic.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***CSS from page***

```
.slider2 {
position: relative;
}
.testimony {
display:table;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #ccccb2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.testimonywide {
display:table;
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #ccccb2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.testimonyhigh {
display:table;
height: 400px;
width: 200px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #ccccb2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.caption-box {
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 20px!important;
width:100px;
background-color: #CCC;
color: #fff;
z-index: 999;
}
.trigger {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.just_text {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
color: #CCC;
}
.trigger.large {
width: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical {
height: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical * {
height: 400px;
}
.hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.static {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px; 
}
.staticlarge {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px; 
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 {
background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img5 {
background-color: #f6c447;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img6 {
background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img7 {
background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img12 {
background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover .hover-img img {
display: none;
}
#container {
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
display: flex;
}
.col {
display:inline-block;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
width: 400px;
}
#apDiv1 {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1;
background-color: #999999;
}
.trigger:hover p {
display:block;
transform:scaleX(-1)
}
 blockquote {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
    content: "“";
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Georgia", Serif;
    color: #F47878;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 5px;
}

cite {
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: "”";
    right: -30px;
    left: auto;
}
body {
text-align: center;

}

.bodyCont{
width :800px;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS as well.

Comment: @dowomenfart ok ill add it now all now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove or change the class **.trigger** on the cards you don't need to flip. That should be enough to avoid the issue with the text.

This way the other 4 cards will still flip but the text on the static cards won't inherit the animation.